# Facebook Graph API python facepy

Tags: python, facebook-comments

I'm using facepy for retrieving fb comments and posts (This is the objective). I've given a valid access token (generated from http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me)

The error generated is:

NameError: name 'AAACEdEose0cBAHshwZCGJ6dHPb0x68c.......D' is not defined. And/OR
facepy.exceptions.OAuthError: [190] Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1359752400.

I believe I've generated the correct access token (with the correct permissions) I thought I would test the facepy library for retrieving photos first. Is their a faster way to retrieve comments, respective user ids, and time stamp from a public fan page (I am guessing most of my target pages have 'public information')

Can someone help me on this?

`from facepy import GraphAPI`

`graph = GraphAPI(AAACEdEose0cBAHshwZCGJ6dHPb0x68c.......D)`

`graph.get('me/posts')`

```
graph.post(
    path = 'me/photos',
    source = open('parrot.jpg')
```

Comment: Shouldn't your API key be in quotes? It's looking for a variable with that name - hence, the NameError.

Comment: `Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1359752400`: tokens expire; you can generate a new one via the Graph API explorer, or via your own app's authorisation flow (using Facebook OAuth).

Comment: Thanks m.brindley - I realized that. But I guess what Richard Barnett said makes sense, the tokens keep expiring. Any way in which I can automate generating the tokens request. (Generating each time from the Graph API seems a pain) –

Comment: @JaySetti: I'm afraid not — OAuth requires user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried with the FB but some of the solutions which worked with other API's.

**Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1359752400.**

Says All. However mostly occurs when I did connected it to some DB for storing some information retrieved from the API.I am sure you have made a right key and password so don't worry about it. Make sure the other connection is still open.

Second, it happened again when I did not accessed the API for weeks so make sure to log in once or twice.

Answer (score -1):

Your API needs to be in quotes...
also generate an extended token via the below